# Not able to access JavaScript Form Elements by using Form Variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm trying to access **Label tag** from inside the **Form tag** using JavaScript for the username validation. If RegEx matches then show Error in the Label otherwise hide that label. When i try to change the text on text field I'm getting following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "style",
> document.forms.form1.uNameError is undefined

**My code:**

```
<body>
<form name="form1">

        // few code here

        <div class="main">
            <input type="text" id="uname" name="username" onchange="checkUsername()">
            <label id="uNameError" style="color: red;">Incorrect name</label> 

        //few code here

        </div>
</form>

<script>
        var form=document.forms['form1'];

        function checkUsername() {
            
            let username=form["uname"].value.trim();
            let validate= /[^a-zA-Z\s]/ig.test(username);
            
            if(validate===true){
                form["uNameError"].style.display="inline";
                
            }else {
                form["uNameError"].style.display="none";
            }

        }
    </script>

</body>
```

How do i reuse my the **form** variable if it is possible.

Comment: You can use `form.querySelector('#uNameError')`

Comment: @ChrisG It's not my first element. Just for demo i have added only few code.

Comment: An `id` is supposed to be unique, so if `<label id="uNameError">` is somewhere inside the form, my code will work. Not sure what you mean by "it's not my first element"? Did you try my code and it failed to work? If so, please add a [mre] to the question so I can point out your mistake

Comment: You can change   `form["uNameError"]` with `document.getElementById("uNameError")` and `form["uname"]` with `document.getElementById("uname").value.trim();` it's the easiest way.

Comment: Yes, so you have more inputs in your form. Even if duplicate `id`s were valid, why would more than one be called `uNameError`? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: @kattie the form variable is correct, but one just can't call `label` tags with `document.forms`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best explanation I can give:

```html
<form name="form1">
  <input type="text" id="uname" name="username">
  <label id="uNameError" style="color: red;">Incorrect name</label>
</form>
<script>
  var form = document.forms['form1']
  console.log(form.elements.length)
</script>
```

By running the above code we can see that the `document.forms.elements` length is 1 although we have a `label` and `input`.
The reason being:

Only these tags can be called using `document.forms`:

```
<button>
<fieldset>
<input> (with the exception that any whose type is "image" are omitted for historical reasons)
<object>
<output>
<select>
<textarea>
```

And we can see that `label` doesn't make it to the list.
Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements).

**Solutions:**

1. You can use `output` instead of `label` for the existing code to work.

   ```html
   <form name="form1">
               <input type="text" id="uname" name="username" onchange="checkUsername()">
               <output id="uNameError" name='uNameError' style="color: red;">Incorrect name</output> 
   </form>

   <script>
           var form=document.forms['form1']

           function checkUsername() {
               
               let username=form["uname"].value.trim();
               let validate= /[^a-zA-Z\s]/ig.test(username);
               
               if(validate===true){
                   form["uNameError"].style.display="inline";
                   
               }else {
                   form["uNameError"].style.display="none";
               }

           }
       </script>
   ```
2. You can call the `label` using its `id`.

```html
<form name="form1">
  <input type="text" id="uname" name="username" onchange="checkUsername()">
  <label id="uNameError" style="color: red;">Incorrect name</label>

</form>

<script>
  var form = document.forms['form1'];

  function checkUsername() {

    let username = form["uname"].value.trim();
    let validate = /[^a-zA-Z\s]/ig.test(username);
    let uNameError = document.getElementById('uNameError')
    if (validate === true) {
      uNameError.style.display = "inline";

    } else {
      uNameError.style.display = "none";
    }

  }

</script>
```

Comment: OP is asking how to access the <label>. <output> is not a <label>. The main difference being that clicking on a properly set up label will activate its input.

Comment: The aim is to solve the problem and not “using `label` tag”. If the code can work without it, then so be it.

Answer (score 0):

document.forms only supports form elements. eg: input, button etc. [Have a look.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp)

To access the label element directly...

1 ) ... The natural way of document.forms

```
form["uname"].labels[0] 
// Note!! 
// A connection must be established between label and input.
// I mean, you have to add a for attribute for="uname" inside label element. uname is id of input element. Then it will possible to get label via .label[0].
```

or

2 ) ... you can select it by the form that you declare before :

```
form.querySelector('#uNameError');
```

or

3 ) ... you can use *[nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling)* :

```
form["uname"].nextElementSibling
```

will give you access to the label that what you need.

So:

```
<body>
    <form name="form1">
            <div class="main">
                    <input type="text" id="uname" name="username" onchange="checkUsername()">
                    <label id="uNameError" for="uname" style="color: red;">Incorrect name</label>
            </div>
    </form>
    
    <script>
            var form=document.forms['form1'];
    
            function checkUsername() {

                let username=form["uname"].value.trim();
                let validate= /[^a-zA-Z\s]/ig.test(username);
                if(validate===true){
                    form["uname"].labels[0].style.display="inline";
                    // or
                    // form.querySelector('#uNameError').style.display="inline";
                    // or
                    // form["uname"].nextElementSibling.style.display="inline";
                }else {
                    form["uname"].labels[0].style.display="none";
                    // or
                    // form.querySelector('#uNameError').style.display="none";
                    // or
                    // form["uname"].nextElementSibling.style.display="none";
                }
            }
        </script>
    
    </body>
```

Off topic. Here I recommend you to use onkeyup instead of onchange and improve your regex structure.

Comment: Thanks for onkeyup. Can you correct my regex?

Comment: @kattie Actually the regex is correct. Since I only see username , I thought maybe it doesn't logically need to contain spaces. But if it belongs to the normal name, there is no problem.